# Hyphema type that doesn't pool?

Tags: blood, eye, hemorrhage

I'm gonna be honest here, I'm writing a story where a guy has the classical evil red eyes you can find everywhere, and I want to base it in science. I've thought about posting this on worldbuilding, but the subject itself is probably more appropreate here. I've come across Hyphema, which would be a perfect fit, but it either pools at the bottom or hinders your vision, then I found Rubeosis Iridis, which isn't "red enough" for me, and albinism doesn't work with the rest of the design. So, my question: is there any variant of these, or something else, that could realistically cause red eyes? I know it might be a dumb question, since in the end I could just suspend my own disbelief, but I know it'd bother me later, and asking here won't hurt.

Comment: Hyphema is when the eye gets injured and there's bleeding on the inside. As per my knowledge there is no such fancy red color eye observed in biology but tell me about your character and I'll try to suggest something because there could be something that you might not know. Just saying that you want a condition where the eye is red could cause you to give a heroic protagonist the bad guy's characteristics.

Comment: [This](https://pixels.com/featured/bleeding-eye-of-patient-with-rubeosis-iridis-sue-fordscience-photo-library.html) isn't red enough for you?

Comment: That's a hyphema, that one's red enough, I meant the Rubeosis Iridis specifically with not "red enough". The main problem when it comes to hyphema is that it sort of impedes basically everything eye-related.

Comment: @Desai The basic story is that magic is science, and in this case tied to blood oxygen, mages can use it to generate power like a body does, but now it's magical energy, not chemical energy. Because the character (villian, by the way) is so supremely powerful, I want it to become visible on the outside, ie make the eyes red, and given the whole magic is science approach, I'm searching for an explaination.